# Not able to store multiple records in an array

Tags: java

I am trying to make a Book Database GUI which inserts the title,author and price of each book in the array created.
There is a search function to search a particular book in the database by its title.
However my code only seems to work for only one book and not for multiple books.
I am trying to enter 10 book details here for instance.
I am only able to search the book which was created the last.

My Code is as follows:

```
class Book{
    public String title,author;
    public int price;
    Book(String t,String a,int p){
        this.title=t;
        this.author=a;
        this.price=p;
    }
}

class Swingdemo implements ActionListener{
    Book B[]=new Book[10];

    JLabel jl1;
    JTextField a1,a2,a3,a4;
    JButton j1,j2,j3;
    Swingdemo() {

        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Welcome");
        jfrm.setSize(180,300); 
        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(jfrm.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        a1 = new JTextField(8);

        a2 = new JTextField(8);

        a3 = new JTextField(8);

        j1 = new JButton("Create");

        a4 = new JTextField(8);

        j2 = new JButton("Search");
        jl1 = new JLabel("Press a Button");
        j1.setActionCommand("1");
        j2.setActionCommand("2");
        j1.addActionListener(this);
        j2.addActionListener(this);
        jfrm.add(a1);
        jfrm.add(a2);
        jfrm.add(a3);
        jfrm.add(j1);
        jfrm.add(a4);
        jfrm.add(j2);
        jfrm.add(jl1); 
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }

    int num=0;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("1")){
            B[num]=new Book(a1.getText(),a2.getText(),Integer.parseInt(a3.getText()));
            jl1.setText("Book has been added");
            num++;
        }

        else{
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<B.length;i++){
                if(B[i].title.equals(a4.getText()))
                    jl1.setText("Book has been found");
            }
            if(i==B.length)         
                jl1.setText("Book was not found");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new Swingdemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: When you find a book you do not exit the loop and keep incrementing i. At the end i is always equal to B.length and you always write "Book was not found".

Comment: Note that the `if(i==B.length)  ` condition will always be matched, at this location of your code, `i` is always equal to `B.length` .

Comment: You need to have a `break` in the `if` condition when it is found

Comment: Get out of the habit of omitting `{}` from blocks. It causes hard-to-spot bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer use Optional wrapper instead of local variable such as found

```
Optional<Book> mbyBook = Optional.empty();
for (Book b : B) {
    if (b.title.equals(a4.getText())) {
       mbyBook = Optional.of(b);
       break;
    }
}
if (mbyBook.isPresent()) {
    jl1.setText(String.format("Book has been found %s", mbyBook));
} else {
    jl1.setText("Book was not found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to solve a problem like this is to separate it from all the irrelevant Swing stuff, into a method of its own:

```
public String findBook(String title) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<B.length;i++){
       if(B[i].title.equals(title))
           return("Book has been found");
       }
       if(i==B.length)         
          return("Book was not found");
    }
}
```

All I have done here is copy/paste your code from `int i` onward, and put it in a method, passing `title` instead of looking directly at the Swing text fields. Then I replaced the `setText`s with `return`.

You can call this by replacing the whole chunk in your main code with:

```
 jl1.setText(findBook(a4.getText());
```

Now the method is independent of Swing, and you can test it on its own.

The first problem is that it won't compile. Now that we've returned the `setText`s with `return` the compiler can noticed that there's a route through the code that doesn't return anything -- where all the `if`s are false.

So let's make it compile, by adding a return at the end. We'll also add braces `{}` so that the `if`s are visually consistent. Never leave out braces, even though the compiler lets you.

```
public String findBook(String title) {
    for(int i=0;i<books.length;i++){
       if(books[i].title.equals(title))
          return("Book has been found");
       }
       if(i==books.length) {        
          return("Book was not found");
       }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I also moved the declaration of `i` into its initialiser. It's a familiar form.

And I renamed `B` to `books`. In Java we tend towards descriptive variable names, and variables always start with a lower-case letter.

Now we have something that compiles. One good approach is to run tests in a debugger (your IDE has one). But we can eyeball this code, and work out what it would do when the book is not found.

Let's say `B[]` is just 3 items long. `i` starts at 0.

- Is `0 < 3` ? Yes. Continue with loop.
- Does `B[0]` match on title? No. Skip if.
- Does `0 == 3`? No.  Skip if.
- `i++` -- `i == 1`
- Is `1 < 3` ? Yes. Continue with loop.
- Does `B[1]` match on title? No. Skip if.
- Does `1 == 3`? No.  Skip if.
- `i++` -- `i == 2`
- Is `2 < 3` ? Yes. Continue with loop.
- Does `B[2]` match on title? No. Skip if.
- Does `2 == 3`? No.  Skip if.
- `i++` -- `i == 3`
- Is `3 < 3` ? No. Exit loop.
- return null

We never pass the `if(i==B.length)` test, because we only ever enter that block when `i<B.length`.

But that `return null` gets hit. So you can make it do what you want by putting the `not found` response *after* the loop:

```
public String findBook(String title) {
    for(int i=0;i<Books.length;i++){
       if(Books[i].title.equals(title))
          return("Book has been found");
       }
    }
    return("Book was not found");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed and great answer i really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean found = false;
for(i=0;i<B.length;i++) {
    if(B[i].title.equalsIgnoreCase(a4.getText().trim())) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
 }
 if(!found)         
     jl1.setText("Book was not found");
 else
     jl1.setText("Book has been found");
```

Or you could also do,

```
for(i=0;i<B.length;i++) {
    if(B[i].title.equalsIgnoreCase(a4.getText().trim())) {
        break;
    }
 }
 if(B.length > 0 && i < B.length)         
     jl1.setText("Book has been found");
 else
     jl1.setText("Book was not found");
```

Comment: Show how to use `equals()` properly please and I'd challenge, that title is a unique identifier for a book...

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't check original code properly, there is no Book instance available to compare with...